# Testing service in Angular returns module is not defined

Tags: unit-testing, angularjs, karma-runner

I am trying to run the default service unit test in my project (Taken from the Angular Seed project on GitHub), but I keep getting the error "module is not defined".

I have read that it could be something to do with the order of the [referenced JavaScript files](https://github.com/vojtajina/testacular/issues/66), but I can't seem to get it to work, so hopefully one of you might be able to help.

My configuration for the test looks like this:

> basePath = '../';
>
> files = [
>   'public/javascripts/lib/jquery-1.8.2.js',
>   'public/javascripts/lib/angular.js',
>   'public/javascripts/lib/angular-*.js',
>
>    'public/app.js',
>
>   'public/controllers/*.js',
>   'public/directives.js',
>   'public/filters.js',
>   'public/services.js',
>   JASMINE,
>   JASMINE_ADAPTER,
>   'public/javascripts/lib/angular-mocks.js',
>   'test/unit/*.js' ];
>
> autoWatch = true;
>
> browsers = ['Chrome'];
>
> junitReporter = {   outputFile: 'test_out/unit.xml',   suite: 'unit'
>   };

The service looks like the following:

```
angular.module('myApp.services', []).
  value('version', '0.1');
```

The test looks like this:

```
'use strict';

describe('service', function() {
  beforeEach(module('myApp.services'));


  describe('version', function() {
    it('should return current version', inject(function(version) {
      expect(version).toEqual('0.1');
    }));
  });
});
```

And the error when running the test through testacular is this:

> ReferenceError: module is not defined

Comment: can you share your project somewhere? I might be able to help. Did you try to turn on DEBUG level for testacular to see which files are actually loaded based on your configuration? For now the suspicious part is this patter: public/javascripts/lib/angular-.js - what should it match?

Comment: @JohnDoe Thanks that worked. If you add an answer I will mark it as resolved. The reason was that I was following the seed project, which did it that way, and which worked. I don't know if it is because it was an earlier version.

Comment: @Dofs Are "'public/javascripts/lib/angular-.js'," and "'public/controllers/.js'" typos?

Comment: @RyanO'Neill sorry, yes this was a typo.

Answer (score 260, accepted):

You are missing the **angular-mocks.js** file.

Comment: Note that `angular.module` and `angular.mock.module` are **not** the same.  The `window.module` function is an alias for `angular.mock.module`.  See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13334749/testing-service-in-angular-returns-module-is-not-defined/14167563#14167563) for more.

Comment: As previous comment says, angular.module is not an alias for angular.mock.module.

Comment: I'm using `requirejs`. I was experience random failing of tests until I added jasmine-boot as a dependency to angular-mocks. To be clear, I _now_ have: `shim: {"angular-mocks": {deps:["angular", "boot"], exports: "angular.mock"}}` and everything works swimmingly! (credit to @Antoine Jaussoin for this solution)

Comment: This answer would be much more useful if it offered any advice about how to provide said file. I needed to install Bower, then NgMocks.

Comment: The answer provides only part of the solution. This is actually a comment and not an explanation. Some of the answers below are much more detailed.

Comment: For the beginners, you need to add a reference to `angular-mocks` in the `karma.conf.js` file,  and run the tests through Karma, not Jasmine. This way, when Karma is run, it picks up the `angular-mocks` extensions and incorporates them into the environment.

Answer (score 41):

I had the same problem, and I understood why it wasn't working:
The jasmine.js javascript **must be referenced BEFORE** the angular-mocks.js file.
Indeed, the angular-mocks.js checks if Jasmine is loaded, and only if it is it will add the module function to the window.

Here is an **extract** of Angular Mocks code:

*(Edit after the few comments about 'hacking' I had below: this is just an extract of the code, this is not something you need to write yourself, it's already there!)*

```
window.jasmine && (function(window) {

[...]

  window.module = angular.mock.module = function() {
    var moduleFns = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0);
    return isSpecRunning() ? workFn() : workFn;
    /////////////////////
    [...]
  };
```

*In a nutshell:*
Just reference your jasmine.js **before** angular-mocks.js and off you go.

Comment: This can also be resolved by making sure the jasmine javascript files are loaded before angular-mocks. Cleaner solution than making hacky changes to get stuff to work.

Comment: @foomip Who suggested making hacky changes?

Comment: You essentially inserted a hack into your app to make sure that things load in the correct fashion - and I didn't mean hack in a bad way (there is nothing wrong with the way you wrote that snippet of code) but what happens when an update to jasmine or something else causes that snippet of your to break or no longer function as expected? It could or couldn't happen, but that is a liability in your code now that could be avoided, don't you think?

Comment: @foomip: I'm not sure what you are referring to, but if it's about my code above, this wasn't written by me, I'm merely quoting it to explain the issue. The code is part of angular-mocks.
The fix is simply a matter of referencing one file before the other.

Answer (score 36):

The `window.module` function comes in [angular-mocks.js](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/f0c6ebc07653f6267acec898ccef5677884e3081/src/ngMock/angular-mocks.js#L1654-L1685) and is a shorthand for `angular.mock.module`.  As mentioned in [the docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/function/angular.mock.module), the `module` function only works with Jasmine.

Using [Testacular](http://vojtajina.github.com/testacular/), the following example configuration file will load `angular-mocks.js`.

```js
/** example testacular.conf.js */

basePath = '../';
files = [
  JASMINE,
  JASMINE_ADAPTER,
  'path/to/angular.js',
  'path/to/angular-mocks.js',   // for angular.mock.module and inject.
  'src/js/**/*.js',             // application sources
  'test/unit/**/*.spec.js'      // specs
];
autoWatch = true;
browsers = ['Chrome'];
```

And, as suggested elsewhere, you can run Testacular with debug logging to see what scripts are loaded (you can also see the same in the inspector):

```
testacular --log-level debug start config/testacular.conf.js
```

The [`angular.mock.inject` docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/function/angular.mock.inject) include a pretty complete example.

Comment: Perhaps worth noting that `module` now also works with mocha

Answer (score 11):

We use 'module' without 'angular' in our unit tests and it works fine.

CoffeeScript:

```
describe 'DiscussionServicesSpec', ->
    beforeEach module 'DiscussionServices'
    beforeEach inject ... etc.
```

which compiles to

JavaScript:

```
describe('DiscussionServices', function() {
    beforeEach(module('DiscussionServices'));
    beforeEach(inject(function ... etc.
```

The only time I see something like the error you described is if in the testacular.conf.js file the angular-mocks.js file is not listed in the files section before the specs trying to use 'module'. If I put it after my tests in the 'files' list I get

```
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: module
```

(Our tests are being run through PhantomJS)

Comment: The thing to conclude is angular-mocks is a requirement.

Answer (score 3):

I had included angular-mocks.js in my karma config, but was still getting the error.  It turns out the order is important in the files array. (duh)  Just like in the head of an html doc, if a script calls angular before it's defined, and error occurs.  So I just had to include my app.js after angular.js and angular-mocks.js.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Yeoman and its angular-generator, you probably get this error. Especially when you do the Tutorial ( ._.) 
 
I fixed it, by copying the angular-mocks.js file, from the bower_components/angular-mocks dir to the test/mock dir. Of course you have to be sure, that your karma.conf.js file is configured correctly. 

Greetings!

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue when I was doing something like `var module = angular.module('my',[])`. I needed to make sure it was surrounded by IIFE