# Grunt + Karma test runner fails with "ReferenceError: module is not defined"

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, karma-runner

When running our Karma test through Grunt, the execution fails with the following error:

```
[2013-12-30 10:14:22.690] [ERROR] config - Invalid config file!
[ReferenceError: module is not defined]
```

The Karma configuration in `Gruntfile.js` looks sane, I've copied it from another project, where it works just fine. Same for the `karma.conf.js` file, there's no difference to one of the other projects, where it works fine.

I've had a look at this question, but it didn't help with fixing the issue: [Testing service in Angular returns module is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13334749/testing-service-in-angular-returns-module-is-not-defined)

I'm not pasting the Grunt or Karma config files since they didn't have any impact on fixing this issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution for this issue was found here: https://github.com/karma-runner/grunt-karma/issues/52

Basically, an old version of the `grunt-karma` module was used as a *dev dependency*, in this case it was version *0.4.3* - here's a snippet from the `package.json` file:

```
{
  "dependencies": {},
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "~0.4.1",
    "grunt-contrib-copy": "~0.4.1",
    "grunt-contrib-concat": "~0.3.0",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "~0.2.5",
    "grunt-karma": "~0.4.3",
    "matchdep": "~0.1.2",
    "karma": "~0.10.2",
    "karma-coverage": "~0.1.0",
    "karma-script-launcher": "~0.1.0",
    "karma-firefox-launcher": "~0.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~0.1.0",
    "karma-html2js-preprocessor": "~0.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~0.1.3",
    "karma-requirejs": "~0.1.0",
    "karma-coffee-preprocessor": "~0.1.0",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "~0.1.0",
    "karma-junit-reporter": "~0.1.0"
  },

  // ...
}
```

Apparently, this older version of `grunt-karma` is causing the `module is not defined` error.

Updating this to use a more recent version (*0.6.2*, which we use in the other project that's working fine) solved the issue:

```
"grunt-karma": "~0.6.2"
```

Then running `npm install` in the project directory downloaded the updated version of `grunt-karma`, and the tests ran fine after that.