# ReferenceError: Can't find variable: module in angular testing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, testing, ionic-framework, karma-jasmine

I'm trying to write a test for my Angular controller, I'm using `jasmine` `karma` and `angular-mocks`, but keeps on getting the error `ReferenceError: Can't find variable: module`.

I had a bit of a [search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13334749/testing-service-in-angular-returns-module-is-not-defined), but I already have the `angular-mocks` in my bower.

What could I be missing here?

The following is my code:

```
#controller
angular.module('cook_book_ctrl', [])
.controller('cookBookCtrl', function($scope, CookBook, CookBookRecipesService){

  $scope.cookbookoptions = true;

  CookBook.list()
   .success(function(data){
     $scope.recipeList = data;
     CookBookRecipesService.loadCookBookRecipes($scope.recipeList);
   })
   .error(function(error){
   })
  });

#controller test
describe('CookBook controller spec', function(){
  var $httpBackend, $rootScope, createController, authRequestHandler

  beforeEach(module('cook_book_ctrl'));
})

#bower.json
{
  "name": "HelloIonic",
  "private": "true",
  "devDependencies": {
    "ionic": "driftyco/ionic-bower#1.0.0",
    "ionic-service-analytics": "master",
    "ionic-service-core": "~0.1.4",
    "angular-mocks": "1.3.13"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "ng-cordova-oauth": "~0.1.2",
    "ng-tags-input": "~2.3.0",
    "angular": "~1.4.0",
    "underscore": "~1.8.3",
    "materialize": "~0.97.0"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "angular": "~1.4.0"
  }
}


   beforeEach(module('cook_book_ctrl'));
})
```

UPDATE: Screenshot added for clarity

[image]

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Besides installing `angular-mocks` through bower, remember to add reference to `angular-mocks.js` in your karma config file, like below

```
config.set({

    basePath: '../',
    port: '8000',

    files: [
      'bower_components/angular/angular.js',
      'bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
      ...
    ]
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, however even after adding the `angular-mock.js` file, still Im getting the same error. I have updated my question with a screenshot for clarity

Comment: Finally got it working @rebornix, thanks for the help. I had to reinstall `jasmine`, `karma` and `angular-mocks` , and this link also helped http://ericnish.io/blog/set-up-jasmine-and-karma-for-angularjs

Answer (score 11):

In my case it was also about wrong order of files path in karma.conf.js.

Was:

```
// list of files / patterns to load in the browser
files: [
  'tests/*.test.js', // this should not be as first!
  'bower_components/angular/angular.min.js',
  'bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
  'app/*.js',

],
```

Should be:

```
// list of files / patterns to load in the browser
files: [
  'bower_components/angular/angular.min.js',
  'bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
  'app/*.js',
  'tests/*.test.js' // now it's cool
],
```

Maybe obvious thing or maybe not? ;-)

Comment: I had the same problem, this is the solution for me