# TypeError: module is not a function AngularJS & Jasmine

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine

In my sample app have I test runner like this

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <!--angular-->
    <script src="../../../Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
    <!--jasmine-->
    <img src="../../../Content/jasmine/jasmine_favicon.png" />
    <link href="../../../Content/jasmine/jasmine.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="../../../Scripts/jasmine/jasmine.js"></script>
    <script src="../../../Scripts/jasmine/jasmine-html.js"></script>
    <script src="../../../Scripts/jasmine/boot.js"></script>
    <!--angular mocks-->
    <script src="../../../Scripts/angular-mocks.js"></script>
    <!--app tests-->
    <script src="../../FavoritesController.js"></script>
    <script src="FavoritesController.Tests.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

FavoritesController:

```
  var module = angular.module('AngularSampleApp', []);
var FavoritesController = module.controller('FavoritesController', function favoritesController($scope) {
    $scope.phones = [
        {
            'name': 'Nexus S',
            'snippet': 'Fast just got faster with Nexus S.'
        },
        {
            'name': 'Motorola XOOM™ with Wi-Fi',
            'snippet': 'The Next, Next Generation tablet.'
        },
        {
            'name': 'MOTOROLA XOOM™',
            'snippet': 'The Next, Next Generation tablet.'
        }
    ];

});
```

FavoritesController.Tests.js

```
describe('FavoritesController', function () {
    beforeEach(module('AngularSampleApp'));
    it('should create "phones" model with 3 phones', inject(function ($controller) {
        var scope = {},
            ctrl = $controller('FavoritesController', { $scope: scope });

        expect(scope.phones.length).toBe(3);
    }));
});
```

But I am getting:

> TypeError: module is not a function

error after I run my tests. Am I missing something?

Comment: You would need to include angular.mocks, https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.x.x/angular-mocks.js where x.x is the version of angular you are using.

Comment: @PSL thanks, I updated my question and I am getting same error. Still.

Comment: Perhaps something is overwriting the module on the window object? did you try using angular.mock.module? Did you try doing a console.log to see what is module?

Comment: angular.mock looks like defined, when I do console.log(angular.mock.module) comes as undefined. weird.

Comment: Yeah i guess you arent using latest version of angular. What does module give you though?

Comment: I am using AngularJS 1.4.4 from nuget.

Comment: So i am assuming mocks is also of the same version?

Comment: Yes I receive them in same bundle.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to include `angular-mocks.js` **after** Jasmine otherwise functions like `module` or `inject` will not be defined.

Moreover you redefine `module`:

```
var module = angular.module('AngularSampleApp', []);
```

So either you rename the variable or put the code inside an IIFE.

Comment: I found similar issue here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13334749/testing-service-in-angular-returns-module-is-not-defined I included AFTER the jasmine references still same error. Still looking online for solution.

Comment: `window.jasmine` is defined in `boot.js`, so that must be included before `angular-mocks.js`.

Comment: Please see my updated question, still getting same error. I will download angular this time from github instead of nuget. Let's see if it make difference.

Comment: omg, it was related with variable name and position of reference I believe. time go to lunch! thanks :)

Comment: including ng-mocks AFTER jasmine did it for me.

Answer (score -3):

Try this line in the tag body:

```
<body ng-app = 'AngularSampleApp'>
```

Comment: Please add context to your answer.