# Angular Unit Testing with karma and jamis

Tags: angularjs, karma-jasmine

I have set up my Angularjs application for unit testing with Karma and Jasmin. but when I try to run my test cases with `karma start` I am getting the error The controller with the name `Myctrl` is not registered.

My application structure is as follows

```
project-folder
  - app
    - components
      - controllers
        - account
          - signInController.js
          - SignUpController.js
  - app.modules.js
  - app.routes.js
  - test
```

This is my app.modules.js

```
let app = angular.module( 'app', [
  'app.config', 'templates', 'ngAnimate', 'ngAria', 'ngCookies', 'ngMessages', 'ngResource', 'ngSanitize',
  'ngTouch', 'ui.router', 'ui.bootstrap', 'ui.utils', 'ui.load', 'ui.jq', 'oc.lazyLoad','angular-cache',
  'ngToast', 'ngFileUpload', 'ngFileSaver', 'angularMoment', 'angulartics', 'angulartics.google.analytics',
  'ngMessages', 'ng.httpLoader'
]);
```

And the karma.config.js file

```
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({

    // base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
    basePath: '',


    // frameworks to use
    // available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
    frameworks: ['jasmine', 'browserify'],

    // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
    files: [
      'dist/libs/jquery/jquery.js',
      'dist/libs/angular/angular.js',
      'dist/libs/angular-ui-router/angular-ui-router.js',
      'dist/libs/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js',
      'dist/libs/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
      'dist/libs/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js',
      'app/app.modules.js',
      'app/app.routes.js',
      'app/config.lazyload.js',
      'app/components/controllers/account/*.js',
      'test/**/*spec.js',
      ],
      . 
      .
```

```
describe('Myctrl Test', function() {

  describe('Myctrl', function() {
    var vm;

    beforeEach(inject(function( ) {
      angular.module('app')
    }));

    beforeEach(inject(function(_$rootScope_, $controller) {
      var scope = _$rootScope_.$new();
      vm = $controller('Myctrl', {$scope: scope});
    }));

    it('test controller', function() {
      expect(vm.title).toBe(null);
    });

  });

});
```

```
app.controller( 'Myctrl', ['$scope', '$state', 'backendApi', 'ngToast', 'access_token', 'FileUploader', 'keys',
function( $scope, $state, backendApi, ngToast, access_token, FileUploader, keys ) {

  $scope.title = "Hello";


}])
```

Comment: also, I have tried to include all the modules present in `app.modules.js` in `karma.conf.js ` but still I am facing the same issue controller is not registered.

Comment: add your spec file

Comment: Add it to your question please, my eyes are bleeding when I read code in comments

Comment: @LuninRoman please check I have added my spec file

Comment: @LuninRoman controller code also added

Answer (score 0):

Before each test you have to register a module.

The problem is that you tried native AngularJS `angular.module('app')`, while you have to use `module('app')` which is an alias for [angular.mock.module](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/function/angular.mock.module)

> This function registers a module configuration code. It collects the
>   configuration information which will be used when the injector is
>   created by inject.

Change your code to

```
beforeEach(function( ) {
  module('app')
});
```

and make sure `Myctrl` belongs to the `app` module.

Consider the following [article](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/unit-testing) `Testing a Controller` section.

FYI: `angular.module('app')` is only required for referencing a module inside angular application, but this function is not actually including module.

Comment: for module('app') code I am getting error. `TypeError: module is not a function`

Comment: This is another problem, something is wrong with `angular-mocks.js` file. Are you sure the file exists for the path you did specify? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13334749/testing-service-in-angular-returns-module-is-not-defined

Comment: yes file exist `dist/libs/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js`.

Comment: try `angular.mock.module('app')` instead of `module('app')`

Comment: `angular.mock.module('app')` with this I can initialize my app. but getting another issue. `require is not defined`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19117092/jasmine-tests-in-karma-uncaught-referenceerror-require-is-not-defined

Comment: I have fixed require is not defined issue. but now I am facing another one that when I am running `karma start` no test are running

Comment: create another question then

Comment: Thank you so much my all issues are solved and now I can run my test cases.